# Getting started with VS213 + dojo + Typescript

Tags: dojo, typescript

I have a dojo (1.10) widget in VS2013. I'd like to start using Typescript. What do I need to configure?  I've installed dojo.d.ts from NuGet

Still get red squiggly and "Cannot find name define"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot find name define

You shouldn't need to use `define` (from requirejs) with TypeScript. TypeScript includes support for `AMD` compilation as a flag (`--module amd`).

More: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1